# I want the <div class="global-tab"> to popup when i hover over the global <li>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the `<div class="global-tab">` to popup when i hover over the global `<li>`

```js
var tabStatus = 1;
function globalTab() {
    if (tabStatus == 1) {
        document.getElementById ('div-global-tab').style.display = 'block'
        tabStatus = 0;
    }   else if (tabStatus == 0) {
        document.getElementById ('div-global-tab').style.display = 'none'
        tabStatus = 1;
    }
}
```

```css
.div-global-tab{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<li><a href="#" onmouseover="globalTab()">Global</a>
                            <div class="div-global-tab">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">North America</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Europe</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">South America</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Asia</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Africa</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Climate Change</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Nature</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Global Disasters</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">The Future</a></li>
                                    <br>
                                    <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
```

When I hover over "Global", I want the div with the class of "div-global-tab" to popup, idk why it doesn't work

Comment: The ID isn't `div-global-tab` so `getElementById('div-global-tab')` returns null. There's a pretty explicit error message if you run your code

Answer (score 1):

You have no element with an id of `global-tab-div`.

That being said, you can achieve this with CSS alone:

```css
#global-tab-div {
  display: none;
}

.global:hover #global-tab-div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<li class="global"><a href="#">Global</a>
  <div id="global-tab-div">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">North America</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Europe</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">South America</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Asia</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Africa</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Climate Change</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nature</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Global Disasters</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">The Future</a></li>
      <br>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="globalTab()" onmouseout="globalTab()">Global</a>
  <div id="global-tab-div" class="global-tab-div">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">North America</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Europe</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">South America</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Asia</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Africa</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Climate Change</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nature</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Global Disasters</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">The Future</a></li>
      <br>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

```
function globalTab() {
  document.getElementById('global-tab-div').classList.toggle("global-tab-div");
}
```

Comment: Solution's good, but it is usually a good idea to inclue an explanation of what you changed. Particularly when the change is so minor it could be hard to identify immediately what changed.